# Why are my hidden divs auto appearing?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, hidden

I have two hidden divs named hidden_div and hidden_divX.  The objective is to make each one appear when the respective checkbox is clicked.  I have two separate functions.  Both are pretty much identical.  The first hidden div works fine.  The second one auto appears.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

JS:

```
function doInput(obj){
    var checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"); 
    var i =0, box;
    $('#hidden_div').fadeOut('fast');

    while(box = checkboxs[i++]){
        if(!box.checked)continue;
        $('#hidden_div').fadeIn('fast');
        break;
    }
}

function doInputs(obj){
    var checkboxs = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"); 
    var i =0, box;
    $('#hidden_divX').fadeOut('fast');

    while(box = checkboxs[i++]){
        if(!box.checked)continue;
        $('#hidden_divX').fadeIn('fast');
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is my current html:

```
<div id="ticket_hidden" style="text-align: center; clear:both;">
    <div id="visible_div" style="float: left;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="escalated" value="Yes" onclick="doInput(this)" tabindex="18">Escalate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="hidden_div" style="float: left;">
        <input type="text" id="escalated_to" name="escalated_to" maxlength="100" style="width:200px; height:18px;" tabindex="19" placeholder="Escalated To">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="visible_divX" style="float: left;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="escalated" value="Yes" onclick="doInputs(this)" tabindex="20">Send Email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div id="hidden_divX" style="float: left;">
        <input type="text" id="escalated_to" name="escalated_to" maxlength="100" style="width:200px; height:18px;" tabindex="21" placeholder="Email To">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add html to the question?

Comment: @dumass Added HTML per request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grab the checked value from `obj` since you're passing in `this` from `doInputs(this)`.

```
function doInput(obj) {
    if ($(obj).is(':checked')) {
        $('#hidden_div').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('#hidden_div').fadeOut('fast');
    }
}

function doInputs(obj) {
    if ($(obj).is(':checked')) {
        $('#hidden_divX').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('#hidden_divX').fadeOut('fast');
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dV2Kb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (say checkbox1 & checkbox2) to each of the checkboxes  & handle events in the below manner instead of using onclick.. For example, handling 1st checkbox click

```
   $('.checkbox1').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#hidden_div').fadeIn('fast');
            //Add more logic
        }
        else
        {
            //more logic
        }
    });
```